# T-SQL Pivot Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'

Tags: t-sql

I'm working on the Datacamp T-SQL course and I can't figure out to use a pivot for some reason.

Start query is:

```
SELECT CategoryID, AVG(UnitPrice) AS Price
FROM Products
GROUP BY CategoryID;
```

Results are:

```
CategoryID     Price      
----------------------
1              37.9791
2              23.0625
3              25.1600
4              28.7300
5              20.2500
6              54.0066
7              32.3700
8              20.6825
```

Results I want:

```
Per Category        1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8
Average Unit Price  37.98   23.06   25.16   28.73   20.25   54.01   32.37   20.68
```

Code I wrote:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT CategoryID, AVG(UnitPrice)
     FROM DBO.Products) AS test
PIVOT 
    (UnitPrice 
     FOR CategoryID IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8])) AS PivotTable
GROUP BY 
    CategoryID
```

But then I get the error

> [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'. (156) (SQLExecDirectW)

I also tried `AVG(UnitPrice)` in the pivot.

It then generated this error:

> [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'UnitPrice'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW)

I've been on this one for a while now, and I have no idea where to look. If someone could point me in the right direction, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there other column in `Products` besides `CategoryID` and `UnitPrice`? (I expect so, but just want to clarify that)

Comment: Yes, ProductID ProductName SupplierID CategoryID QuantityPerUnit UnitPrice UnitsInStock UnitsOnOrder ReorderLevel Discontinued are all in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there are more columns in `Products` than just those shown, I think you want:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT CategoryID, UnitPrice
FROM DBO.Products) as test
PIVOT (
     AVG(UnitPrice) FOR
     CategoryID IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8])
) AS PivotTable
```

`PIVOT` hides an explicit grouping which we don't need to repeat. If `Products` only contains `CategoryID` and `UnitPrice`, we can use it directly rather than the `test` subquery

Comment: So basically i just needed to use the AVG funtion in the pivot and not in the subquery.. Damn, Thanks alot tho!

Comment: @MilkTea - yes, like I said, there's a hidden `GROUP BY` in `PIVOT` which is basically "all columns in the existing result set except for the column placed in the pivot aggregate". That's why we need the subquery to remove the other columns from the table before we attempt the `PIVOT`.

Comment: Sorry to keep asking, as i said before im kinda new to this pivoting part. it seems i cant use ROUND() to round the decimals to 2.

Also, how do i add Names to the table? as shown in the example: Per Category and Avarage unit price?

Thanks Again.

Comment: I tried this exact syntax and it gets the same error as the OP. downvote.

Comment: @pianocomposer - whilst I of course welcome feedback, this answer was accepted by the OP as solving their problem and I'm not seeing any obvious errors in the construction here. Are you sure it's the *same* error as the OP reported?

Answer (score 0):

I would remove `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT CategoryID, UnitPrice FROM DBO.Products) as test
PIVOT (AVG(UnitPrice) FOR CategoryID IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8])
      ) AS PivotTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  CategoryID, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8] FROM 

(SELECT price, CategoryID from dbo.Products) x 

PIVOT (
 MAX(price) FOR
 CategoryID IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8])
) AS PivotTable
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
SELECT 'Average Unit Price' AS 'Per Category',   
[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8]
FROM  
(SELECT CategoryID, UnitPrice   
    FROM dbo.Products) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
AVG(UnitPrice)  
FOR CategoryID IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8])
) AS PivotTable;
```